# Should i not do write actions via GET?

Tags: html, search-engine, bots

I was told to never do write operations with GET request. and that search engines and other bots would follow and activate them. Assuming all write operations require a login would there be a problem having get request as a link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing with a GET violates [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer). There are more fundamental and philosophical reasons for doing this than just because a bot will follow them. That doesn't mean that it's not allowed though.

The reason a GET should not cause a write operation is that in a RESTful service, there is an implicit agreement that GETs are "safe", and will not cause anything to happen remotely. A GET is just for getting information. If you want to send information, use POST.

Comment: +1 for mentioning both the good reasons to follow the law and that the law isn't absolute.

Comment: hmm. I have an action called watch user which links to `/watch_user?action=<true or false>&id=<user_to_watch_id>&tok=<RandomCookieValueSoImageCantTriggerThis>` This would be bad? its undo able.

Comment: i could but i dont see the problem with get since logouts also do write actions (depending on the webapp). I like get since if the user logged out i can ask for a login and not have him redo the watch action. -edit- i guess i could use post since the RandomCookieValueSoImageCantTriggerThis is likely to change every login.

Comment: If writing with GET is against REST, then how do you suggest tracking the number of views for a certain article or forum post? I can't see any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Not only bots, but regular browsers behave differently for GET request. When you use "back" button on a page that uses POST, most browsers give you a warning that resending the request will do (presumed) write operation again. There is no such thing with GET, because it's presumed that GET does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

A login will not protect a user from the danger of link prefetching done by their browser, browser add-ons (including link previewers), "web accelerator", or even proxy server.

Comment: d'oh. What about GET with ajax? thankfully i took advice and changed them to post but i would love to know if you know if web accelerators will grab data with ajax get

Comment: @acidzombie24 I've never heard of that happening, and would imagine it to be less likely, but any data-changing GET request could bite you, AJAX or not. If a browser makes a request that ends up in a cache, that cache has the potential to be silently "refreshed" as a performance aid, for example. I'm not saying this is likely. Just that there's no need to worry about all of these crazy scenarios with POST—that's why it's there.